# If a non-mammal is starved of oxygen for some time, how long would it take the animal's neurons to die?

Tags: neuroscience

This is a follow-up question to [Why do neurons die so quickly (relative to other cells) when deprived of oxygen?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/why-do-neurons-die-so-quickly-relative-to-other-cells-when-deprived-of-oxygen).

I'm particularly interested in the case of reptiles, octopuses, and other invertebrates. Could it be that mammalian neurons are especially oxygen-demanding compared with the neurons of other animals?

Comment: I believe, it mostly depends on external parameters rather then organism type. [The humans could revive after up to 72 hours of clinical death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_death#Controlled_clinical_death) with specific treatment, while under normal conditions irreversible damage occurs after 5-10 minutes. [Some frogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_Frog), for example, can survive being frozen for several months.

Answer (score 2):

Medically, [recovery of brain function after 3 minutes of oxygen deprivation at body temperature is rare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_death#Limits_of_reversal).

Further down here in [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_death#Limits_of_reversal) it indicates that at lower temperatures the time can be much longer.  At 13C, the record is 80 minutes for people.  Animals cooled to 0C have a record of recovery of three hours!  Not sure how much like themselves they feel after that though...